# fractal dimension of the Sierpinski carpet

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to find the fractal dimension $d$ of the [Sierpinski carpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet), $$d= \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\ln N(k)}{\ln(k)}$$ Where $N(k)$ is the minimal number of squares of the size $(1/k)\times (1/k) $ covering the Sierpinski carpet.

We observe that $$N(3)=8 \ \ \ , \ \ \ N(9)=64 \ \ \ , \ \ \ N(27)=8^3 \ \ \ , \ \ldots \ \ , \  N(3^j)=8^j \ \ \ldots$$  Now if we compute the limit along the index set $\{k_1,k_2,k_3,\ldots\} = \{3,9,27,81,\ldots\}$ we would have : $$ \lim_{k_j \to \infty} \frac{\ln N(k_j)}{\ln k_j}=  \lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{\ln 8^j}{\ln 3^j}=  \lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{j \ln 8}{j \ln 3}= \frac{ \ln 8}{ \ln 3}$$

How can I rigorously show that the limit computed along this subsequence is actually equal to the limit :    $\ \ \ \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\ln N(k)}{\ln(k)} \ \ \ $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $N(k)$ is a nondecreasing function of $k$ (since if we can cover something with $N$ squares of size $(1/k)\times (1/k)$, we can also cover with $N$ squares of any larger size.)

For any positive integer $k$, there exists a nonnegative integer $j$ such that $3^{j}\le k< 3^{j+1}$. Therefore, $$8^j = N(3^{j})\le N(k) \le N(3^{j+1}) = 8^{j+1}$$
Take logarithm and divide by $\ln k$:
 $$\frac{j \ln 8}{\ln k}\le \frac{\ln N(k)}{\ln k} \le \frac{(j+1) \ln 8} {\ln k}$$

Use inequalities $\ln k \ge j\ln 3$ and $\ln k\le (j+1)\ln 3$:
 $$\frac{j \ln 8}{(j+1) \ln 3}\le \frac{\ln N(k)}{\ln k} \le \frac{(j+1) \ln 8} {j \ln 3}$$
The middle term is squeezed between two things that both approach $\ln 8 / \ln 3$.